# When spring config server is down and GIT under maintenance and spring config client at the initial startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Spring Config-Client is in initial startup so It would not have cached the data from config server,
if either Config-Server or GIT or both are down -  what can be done in that case to get the data and maintain service availability.

Comment: You can set a `spring.cloud.config.fail-fast=true` and include spring retry so the service will retry for so long using an exponential backup, but it would fail to startup without configuration. You can mitigate git with local caches for config server.

Comment: Yes. @spencergibb But in my case there are not only configuration files but also some actual data files like .json so I have used JgitEnvironmentRepository to read files. So is there any way out.

Comment: No there isn't. Config server is for configuration, not data. I don't know what to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following (basedir) element of yml file with following hierarchy.
The **"basedir"** element will cache your config data whenever application restarts and keep that on the specified path which is specified against this key as a value.
Example :
basedir : C:\POC_CONFIG_SERVER\config-repo-am

```
server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  application:
    name: cloud-config-server
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: ${uri}
          force-pull: true
          skip-ssl-validation: true
          skipSslValidation: true
          username: ${username}
          password: '${password}'
          default-label: master
          basedir: ${basedir}
```